# Issue deserializing (protocolBuffer) serialized data using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I serialized data using protobuf-net, and am able to deser the same in C#.

## putting a C# dummy w#

```
var file = File.Create("animal.bin");
//Creating Msg - Fill the Data
animal.id = "1";
animal.Name = "Rat";
animal.host = "Cheetha";
ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, animal, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
animal.id = "2";
animal.Name = "Cat";
animal.host = "Cheetha";
ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, animal, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
....
animal.id = "4";
animal.name = "Cheetha";
animal.host = "Cheetha";
ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, animal, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
//Done Creating Msg
file.Close();
```

So far so good... No Issues here. But when I try to deserialize the same in C++ using protocol-buffer, I am unable to get the correct data

## cpp code...

```
GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION; 
string fpath = "animal.bin";

fstream input(fpath, ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!input)
{
    cerr << "failed to open " << fpath << endl;
    return false;
}
ZeroCopyInputStream *raw_in = new IstreamInputStream(&input);
CodedInputStream *coded_in = new CodedInputStream(raw_in);
google::protobuf::uint32 n;
std::string tmpStr;
animal::animalInfo animalList;

coded_in->ReadVarint32(&n);
cout << "# " << n << endl;  //output: #10
coded_in->ReadRaw(&tmpStr,n); //tmpStr shows data like >>1..Rat..Ch 
animalList.ParseFromArray(&tmpStr,1);//Not sure if this is correct usage?
```

I am sure I am making a mistake but not able to understand whats wrong.... Have read and reread lots of post on this but dont see whats still wrong

Using Protocol Buffer2.5, protobuf-netR622, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just mismatching the headers; a length-prefix *and* a field-header (of field 1) is **two** "varint"s; the *first* "varint" will always be decimal 10 (10 means: field 1, length-prefixed). The *second* "varint" tells you the length of the next data. So - if you want to decode it *manually* you would call `ReadVarint32` a *second* time. I'm not familiar with `ReadRaw`, but if the second parameter is the number of bytes to read, then *it goes there*, i.e.

```
coded_in->ReadVarint32(&n); // field header
// assert: n === 10
coded_in->ReadVarint32(&n); // length
coded_in->ReadRaw(&tmpStr,n);
```

Alternatively, just use a wrapper object - i.e.

```
message animals {
    repeated animal items = 1;
}
```

and deserialize it *as an instance of `animals`* - this uses the exact same layout. The only difference here is that it will load *all* the items in one go - so it might be problematic if you are reading very long streams.

Another alternative would be: *don't add a field-header*:

```
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, animal, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
```

Then you would only read one "varint":

```
coded_in->ReadVarint32(&n); // length
coded_in->ReadRaw(&tmpStr,n);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc! Can you say what is the standard/recommended way of reading 1 msg @ a time from the protocbuf-net serialized data in C++. I am now able to get the correct data by using the following `coded_in->ReadVarint32(&n);
cout << "#" << n << endl;  //output: #10
coded_in->ReadVarint32(&n);
cout << "Num Bytes #" << n << endl;  //output: #10
coded_in->ReadString(&tmpStr,n); 
animalList.ParseFromString(tmpStr);`

Comment: It does, thanks.. I was wondering what is recommended way to extract 1 msg @ a time in protocol buffer c++. I can use my scheme marked above but guess a better n direct way is already provided

Comment: @Vic I'm not really a c++ coder, so I'm not an expert in that API. There was talk of adding a streaming API along these same lines (which incidentally maps 100% to DeserializeItems in protobof-net), but AFAIK it didn't come to anything. There may be a length-limited stream, though - rather than reading each item into a buffer. I know the java API provides a length-limited stream implementation. Check for that, maybe. The protobuf-net implementation allows you to specify the amount to read via `ProtoReader`, but I guess you don't need to go to that level anyway.